# Connecting a Spring Boot API to a JSP interface

Tags: spring-boot, jsp

Im pretty new to this, I made an interface using JSP where the user can enter his info like a registration page, and made a Spring Boot API to use CRUD operations in a MySQL database. Im not sure how to connect the two though. Spent a few hours googling and still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go throgh bellow link. You will get a good idea in Spring boot CRUD with jsp.
Follow this [link](http://adnjavainterview.blogspot.com/2019/02/spring-boot-with-jsp-crud-example.html)